# Pass unique image with each selected value option displayed

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

This code works great to have a drop down, target the selected option and display each option in another div when selected. Thanks for the help @Arun P Johny. However, I need to pass a unique picture for each option selected that is displayed in a different div. How would I add that in the jquery? Because the css is just displaying the button for each selected option. Here is a screen shot to give better understanding.
http://postimg.org/image/km36m9jpp/24794463/

Jquery

```
$(function() {
$("#events").hide();
$("#myselect select").change(function() {
  var $selected = $('#myselect select option:selected');
  if (!$selected.hasClass('added')) {
  $('<li />', {
    'data-value': $selected.val(),
    text: $selected.text()
    }).appendTo('#events');
    $selected.addClass('added')
    }
  $("#events").show();
});
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-    awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Add Event To Location</h3>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="row">
        <div id="myselect" class="col-md-12">

          <p>If you have previously created a template for your digital banner please select it from the list, otherwise select no template.</p>
          <form>
            <select id="whatever" name="name_of_selectbox">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="1">Test</option>
              <option value="2">Testing</option>
            </select>
          </form>
          <hr/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p></p>

</div>
<ul id="events"></ul>

CSS

#events li{
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#events li:first-child{
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: do you have a css class to show the image... or an image url?

Comment: I am using dummy data so any relative path would work or absolute path http url. I will be using relative in the app. For the sake of demonstration, here is an image link to use http://postimg.org/image/lnhl1x0g9/1b8eee49/

Comment: see the answer below.... it uses an image url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the image url's to be displayed, then you can use a `data-img` attribute against each option as given below

```js
$(function() {
  $("#events").hide();
  $("#myselect select").change(function() {
    var $selected = $('#myselect select option:selected');
    if (!$selected.hasClass('added')) {
      $('<li />', {
        'data-value': $selected.val(),
        text: $selected.text()
      }).prepend('<img src="' + $selected.data('img') + '"/>').appendTo('#events');
      $selected.addClass('added')
    }
    $("#events").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#events li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#events li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-    awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Add Event To Location</h3>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="row">
        <div id="myselect" class="col-md-12">

          <p>If you have previously created a template for your digital banner please select it from the list, otherwise select no template.</p>
          <form>
            <select id="whatever" name="name_of_selectbox">
              <option value="" data-img="//placehold.it/32x32/ff0000&text=Select">Select</option>
              <option value="1" data-img="//placehold.it/32x32/00ff00&text=Test">Test</option>
              <option value="2" data-img="//placehold.it/32x32/0000ff&text=Testing">Testing</option>
            </select>
          </form>
          <hr/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>You can add an event created in MyApplication.</p>

</div>
<ul id="events"></ul>
```